# Can I add different canvas strokes into an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, javafx, switch-statement

I am currently using a switch/case grouping to add body parts to my hangman game. As the incorrect guesses increase, a limb is added. This is forming a long switch block and was wondering if I can add each case to an array, ArrayList, TreeMap, etc. of some sort and call the body parts based on their index number? Some are strokeLines, while others are strokeOvels.

I am not a student, but was helping a friend who is and while I coded this myself, I am stuck at a rode block with ugly code. That said, due to this being used for many CS classes (based on google searches), I am changing the numbers to X's and Y's. I am here for help, not to hand others a cheatsheet to their assignments.

```
public void paint(){
    GraphicsContext g = gameCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

    switch (newGame.getIncGuessMade()){
        case 0:{
            //gallows...
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
            g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);
        }
        break;
        case 1: g.strokeOval(X,Y,X,Y);     //head
            break;
        case 2: g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);     //chest
            break;
        case 3: g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);     //Right Arm
            break;
        case 4: g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);     //Left Arm
            break;
        case 5: g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);     //Right Leg
            break;
        case 6: g.strokeLine(X,Y,X,Y);     //Left Leg
            break;
        case 7: g.strokeOval(X,Y,X,Y);     //Right Eye
            break;
        case 8: g.strokeOval(X,Y,X,Y);     //Left Eye
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** You could do a 2d array.

```
double[][] strokes = new double[][] {
    { ... },
    ...
    { ... }
};
```

Then,

```
public void paint(){
    GraphicsContext g = gameCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    int i = newGame.getIncGuessMade();
    g.strokeLine(strokes[i][0], ..., strokes[i][3]);
}
```

Of course, you would have to handle the gallows and others with different methods a little differently with a check on `i` which makes it less than great.

---

**Option 2:** I would opt for a `Gallows` with a `draw(g)` method that is constructed with the values and stored there. The same argument could be made for all the drawing components as well.

```
public interface Drawable {
    void draw(GraphicsContext g);
}

public class Gallows implements Drawable {
    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {
        // call what you need to draw the gallows.
    }
}

public class Head implements Drawable {
    @Override
    public void draw(GraphicsContext g) {
        // call what you need to draw the head.
    }
}
```

Each of these drawables will have their coordinates locally. The calling code need not know any details of what `draw` means for each; it only needs to know to call `draw` on them.

---

**Option 3:** If you don't like that way and you're using Java 8 you could have the same 2d double array as before and write `BiConsumer<GraphicsContext, double[]>`s and store them in an array or list as well. Example:

```
BiConsumer<GraphicsContext, double[]> chest = (g, strokes) -> {
    g.strokeLine(strokes[0], ..., strokes[3]); 
};
```

You'd then call it like:

`chest.accept(g, strokes[i]);`

or, assuming it's in an array, like this:

`consumers[i].accept(g, strokes[i]);`

Comment: I like were this is going, but just have the problem of some of the strokes are not strokeLine and would through an exception error. How would I handle the strokeOval(s) in this loop?

Comment: @SkiftWolf, I think the best practice is to have drawable objects. I added some code. It may seem like a lot but in the end you simply have an array or list of `Drawable`s and do `drawables[i].draw(g);` and let the magic happen.

Comment: @SkiftWolf, sorry about missing the different strokes.

Comment: @SkiftWolf, added another option if you prefer less code.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will try to use the 3rd method within my code. As a former student and an all around code geek, I like learning new things. I have not yet used BiConsumer before and would like to play around with it.  Thank you.